# Вопрос про архитектуру баз данных SQL

Tags: sql

Допустим, есть таблица students. В ней хранятся: имя студента, возраст и т.д.
С этим всё понятно. А теперь допустим, что есть элемент techs в котором лежат технологии которыми овладел студент. Как мне правильно сконструировать базу данных? То есть, нужно ли мне создавать отдельную таблицу techs и закинуть туда id студента или можно как-то это всё запихнуть в единственную таблицу students? Речь идёт о реляционных базах данных

Comment: Стандартным подходом является создание отдельной таблицы. И связь один-ко-многим или многие-ко-многим. / Но можно и в единственную таблицу запихнуть. Сейчас многие РСУБД имеют тип данных JSON. Также некоторые имеют тип данных XML или массив.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создавать надо две отдельные таблицы для `Students` и `Techs`, а также необходимо определить связь между ними по полю, которое уникальное (как правило это и есть `id`).

Большинство высокоуровневых языков имеют библиотеки, модули или фреймворки для работы с базами данных. В том числе и автоматического создания таблиц и отношений между ними. То есть для программиста это выглядит, как написание классов в ООП, а при миграции в базу данных создаются таблицы.

Тут важно отметить, что отношение между таблицами могут строиться с использованием дополнительных таблиц (посредников), которые для осваивающих, могут быть не очевидны, то есть за кулисами при миграции создается таблица, которая хранит отношения для двух других, например.

Answer (score 1):

В классическом SQL, обычно, создается таблица-связка, в которую записываются пары связей: `id студента - id технологии`. Таким образом, каждый студент сможет с легкостью владеть никакой, одной или многими технологиями.